# Stickyfill not workiing in Safari and Firefox

Tags: firefox, safari, sticky

Im using stickyfill (https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill) for stickying sidebar menu on scroll.

On safari and Opera it works perfect, but it doesn't work in Safari and Firefox at all. Could please someone help me to solve the problem?

Im using latest version of Wordpress (4.6.1) and Bootstrap (3.3.7).

Website url (Look left sidebar menu):  [HERE](http://dev.parodontologija.si/boleznizdravljenje/oblike/)

JQ:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#sidestick').Stickyfill();
});
```

CSS:

```
.sidestick {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.sidestick:before,
.sidestick:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
}

.sidestick:after {
    clear: both;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .sticky-eq-height {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display:         flex;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content" class="site-content">
<div class="container">
<div class="row sticky-eq-height">

<div class="col-sm-3" >
<div id="sidestick" class="sidestick" style="top: 140px;">
Menu content
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
MAIN CONTENT
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve problem with changing plugin StickyKit (http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/)